# How to verify sending domain for SparkPost in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: php, azure, dns, sparkpost

I am using SparkPost as my sending mail server. When the site was in my development server I have verified the sending domain by making a entry to the DNS from the WHM panel.

Now I have deployed the website in Microsoft Azure. There I have created a DNS Zone then followed same step for domain verification but it seems not be working fine here.

1. Can I send email by using SparkPost without verifying sending
   domain?
2. If yes then how to verify it in Microsoft Azure?
3. How to setup DKIM / Domain key in azure or publish SPF or DKIM DNS records for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what is wrong there for not recognizing what you've tried. However, you can verify sending domain by following the steps below.

### 1. [Create your Sending Domain to work with SparkPost](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1933318-create-and-verify-sending-domains).

[image]

### 2. Once Sending Domain has been created, click on Settings link. The Hostname and Value will be both displayed in the SparkPost UI.

[image]

### 3. [Add a TXT record with Domain Providers](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/2034498-setting-up-spf-and-dkim-with-domain-providers) (here I'm using GoDaddy).

[image]

### 4. [Click Test link to verify the Sending Domain](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1933360).

[image]

### Once your Sending Domain has been verified, you can set email with this domain.

[image]

### EDIT: How to setup DKIM/ Domain key in Azure?

### 1. [Create a DNS zone in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-create-dnszone-portal).

### 2. [Delegate your domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation#delegating-a-domain-to-azure-dns) (change the name server records for the domain).

[image]

[image]

### 3. Navigate to your DNS zone in the Azure Portal, and set up DKIM by adding a TXT record.

[image]

### 4. Now you can verify Sending Domain in SparkPost UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is How to setup DKIM/ Domain key in azure?

Comment: Have you delegated your domain to Azure DNS?

Comment: Sorry i don't have much knowledge in this area. Can please explain about "change the name server records for the domain" step-2 second image.